# Software where I can upload a bunch of images and it will randomly select a handful of them?

Tags: windows, gratis, images, image-processing, image-viewer

Something that works in Windows 10 and is free. Preferably shows them all in a row or in 2 even rows (one on top of the other). Willing to use a website too. Thanks in advance! This is for study and would really make my life so much easier :)

Comment: Select them for what? Display to the user? Edit to clarify your goal.

Answer (score 1):

An oldie question, but I'll add my 2 cents to it.

I am guessing you need some sort of "exam type" stuff, where it randomly selects some images and you need to answer what they are.

I would make a custom script made in PHP and run it locally.

The program would need to:

- Read the names of all images from a designated folder.
- Randomize the name list.
- Display some of them, let's say 10
- The "row" requisite is simply a stylish thing that can be done in CSS.

---

You would need to install a WAMP, this is, install a server (apache) on your computer, that can run PHP. And simply see the results in any browser.

---

For the script, you need some homework, that probably is out of the scope of the forum, it is more a StackOverflow question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122218/get-all-the-images-from-a-folder-in-php

http://php.net/manual/es/function.shuffle.php